# How to construct a 'sliding matrix' using identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following problem: let consider a vector $a=(a_1, ..., a_N)^T$. I would like to construct a 'sliding matrix' A so that:

$A=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & ... & a_1 & 0 & & & ... & & & 0 \\  0 & ... & 0 & a_2 & ... & a_2 & 0 & ... & & 0 \\  0 &  &  & ... &  & 0 & \ddots &  & & \\  0 &  &  &  & ... &  & 0 & a_N & ... & a_N \end{pmatrix}\in K^{N\times NM}$

Each element of $a$ is repeated $M$ times in $A$, which has a size $N\times NM$. For the moment, I only found the means to obtain a unitary $M$, using a kronecker product $I_N \otimes 1_M$...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're saying about your usage of the Kronecker product. In any case, your matrix can be written in the form $D \otimes \mathbf 1^T$, where
$$
D = \operatorname{diag}(a) = \pmatrix{a_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && a_n}, \quad \mathbf 1 = (1,\dots,1)^T.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting with $$I_N \otimes \vec{1}_M^T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & ... & 1 & 0 & & & ... & & & 0 \\  0 & ... & 0 & 1 & ... & 1 & 0 & ... & & 0 \\  0 &  &  & ... &  & 0 & \ddots &  & & \\  0 &  &  &  & ... &  & 0 & 1 & ... & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$ we simply need to multiply the first row by $a_1$, the second row by $a_2$, ..., and the $N$-th row by $a_N$. This can be done with a diagonal matrix multiplication on the left, i.e. $$\text{diag}(a)(I_N \otimes \vec{1}_M^T) = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & ... & a_1 & 0 & & & ... & & & 0 \\  0 & ... & 0 & a_2 & ... & a_2 & 0 & ... & & 0 \\  0 &  &  & ... &  & 0 & \ddots &  & & \\  0 &  &  &  & ... &  & 0 & a_N & ... & a_N \end{pmatrix}$$ where of course $\text{diag}(a) = \begin{pmatrix}a_1 & & & \\  & a_2 & & \\ & & \ddots & \\ & & & a_N \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: so obvious that I didn't even see it.... Thanks!!

Comment: Actually, use Ben Grossmann's answer since it is simpler.